# How do I apply a grading curve to a vector created using rnorm?

Tags: r

I am brand new to R Studio and am very confused.  I did run a search and could not find an answer.  How do I apply a grading curve to this vector created using rnorm?

grades<-c(rnorm(n=200,mean=68,sd=10))

Comment: You might want to give some more information on what you mean by "grading curve"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.